# Log file is growing up and is not releasing space

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, sql-server-2017, logs, recovery-model

The database is under Full Recovery Method, the DBCC SQLPERF (LOGSPACE) shows 3 % used. Even after I take Log back ups frequently it is not releasing space. There is no active transaction and log_reuse_wait_desc reports as nothing.

How do i prevent the log from growing since the log back up is not truncating the log files

Comment: The linke given above answers another question, it'a about a log RUNNING OUT OF SPACE. The OP says that the log is only 3% full, there is NO log running out of spase. There is only a misconception of what "log truncation" means

Comment: >>>the log back up is not truncating the log files<<< Your log backups **do truncate log files**, otherwise your log was full, but it's only 3% full. You just misunderstand "log truncation". It does not mean space release, it just means that the log space can be reused, and in fact it's reused in your case. You should do absolutely nothing, your log file has no problem at all

Comment: So you meant to say that for example if my Log file size is 10 Gb and 5 gb is being used even i am taking frequent log backups and the log_reuse_wait_desc reports as nothing the 5 gb that it shows as being used wont clear up